# Unable to resolve "./SafeAreaContext"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I recently set up [`react-native` project with expo](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) and later on I added `@react-navigation` packages.

It seems like this wasn't enough as `NavigationContainer` render complains about `SafeAreaContext`

I tried to install required packages with `expo install react-native-safe-area-context ...` but It didn't solve it.

Thought deleting `node_modules` && `npm install` could help, but it didn't work either.

[There were related questions to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61995712/unable-to-resolve-safeareacontext-from-react-native-safe-area-context)
, [but they didn't provide much help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407851/react-navigation-4-x-version-issue-when-navigating-to-other-screen)

**I will appreciate your help.**

Here's what I get in android emulator

[image: red screen of death by react=native]

**terminal**

```
Unable to resolve "./SafeAreaContext" from "node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\src\index.tsx"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function Test() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}
    >
      <Text>Test</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
 const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);


  if(!loaded) {
    return <AppLoading
      startAsync={() => Promise.resolve()}
      onFinish={() => setLoaded(true)}/>
  }

  return <NavigationContainer>
    </NavigationContainer>
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1",
    "expo": "^37.0.12",
    "expo-asset": "^8.1.5",
    "expo-constants": "^9.0.0",
    "expo-linking": "^1.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.2.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "^8.2.1",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.23",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.61.17",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Try to add a wrap `return (<NavigationContainer></NavigationContainer>)` , I'm not sure if it help

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem with expo 37.0.3 trying to follow the Hello React Navigation tutorial: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Look like cleaning expo cache helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998636/how-can-i-clean-reset-cache-of-react-native-using-expo-not-sure-if-it-is-cach)

`expo r -c`

`expo r --help`

```
Usage: start|r [options] [project-dir]
Starts or restarts a local server for your app and gives you a URL to it
```

```
 Options:
    -c, --clear           Clear the Metro bundler cache
   ....
```

```
expo --version
3.21.3
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent 3 hours trying to resolve this

Comment: Hello Jozef, I am having this issue. Trying to fix for three days now. How did you solve this? The cache thing does not work

Answer (score 2):

Installing following two,

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view

npm install react-native-safe-area-context
```

it is work for me